# retain the first few duplicates based on a column value

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a time series data which contains 5 columns. first column is the user name, and rest are the values at different points of time. Sample data shown here - https://pastebin.com/raw/TzmhKybt

I want to retain the first 3 values of any given user, and remove the rest. So for every given user, there will be at most 3 records in the data set. I have tried the following but it does not seem to work. Please point me in the right direction as I could not find any good way to do this.
`data %>% group_by(User) %>% top_n(3)`

Output of `dput(data[1:10,])` is

```
structure(list(User = c("mmcclafl", "mmcclafl", "mmcclafl", "mmcclafl", 
"mmcclafl", "mmcclafl", "gsnabwez", "gsnabwez", "gsnabwez", "gsnabwez"
), StartTime = c(584.93, 584.93, 584.93, 584.93, 584.93, 584.93, 
1501.26, 1501.26, 1501.26, 1501.26), Time = c(597.94, 675.28, 
774.02, 843.05, 1093.79, 1142.85, 1510.94, 1582.81, 1665.26, 
1689.91), SelfReport = c("FLOW", "FLOW", "FLOW", "FRUSTRATION", 
"FRUSTRATION", "FRUSTRATION", "FLOW", "FRUSTRATION", "FRUSTRATION", 
"FRUSTRATION"), Affectiva = c("BOREDOM", "BOREDOM", "BOREDOM", 
"BOREDOM", "BOREDOM", "BOREDOM", "BOREDOM", "BOREDOM", "OTHER", 
"BOREDOM")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you update your post by using `dput(df)` and show expected output for the data shared?

Comment: Is there a better way to do this. My actual data contains thousands of rows, and if I do this it will be very tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select first 3 rows for each group by doing.

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(User) %>% slice(1:3)

#  User     StartTime  Time SelfReport  Affectiva
#  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    
#1 gsnabwez     1501. 1511. FLOW        BOREDOM  
#2 gsnabwez     1501. 1583. FRUSTRATION BOREDOM  
#3 gsnabwez     1501. 1665. FRUSTRATION OTHER    
#4 mmcclafl      585.  598. FLOW        BOREDOM  
#5 mmcclafl      585.  675. FLOW        BOREDOM  
#6 mmcclafl      585.  774. FLOW        BOREDOM
```

In base R

```
subset(data, ave(StartTime, User, FUN = seq_along) <= 3)
```

and in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[1:3], by=User]
```

Comment: second option is better than first one, group_by messes with the original order of my data